# android socket chat program error

Tags: java, android, chat

In Emulater when I write texts at the EditText and then click the button,
the texts don't appear at the Textview.
I don't no what is wrong.. Is this the Server problem or Client problem?

Here is the Client(android) code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket sock;
    BufferedReader din;
    BufferedWriter dout;
    EditText text;
    Button button;
    TextView output;
    String msg;
    String str;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);       
    output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String msg = text.getText().toString();
            send(msg);
            text.setText("");
        }
    });




    Thread Th = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
                din = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                dout = new BufferedWriter(new   OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
                while (true) {
                    str = din.readLine();
                    output.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            output.setText(str + "\n");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    Th.start();
}



public void send (String msg) {
    try {
        dout.write(msg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder what's the problem in my code especially textview and EditText

Answer (score 0):

Use `emit()` and events instead of writing and reading from stream.It is easy to handle and manage the events.You can find a sample [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) on how to use socket.io.Following is the simple implementation.Use events to recognise what you are sending and receiving on both server and client side.For example,if client emits on "send" event,the server should listen for the message on "send" event.

```
    Socket mSocket;
    try{
      mSocket = IO.socket("127.0.0.1:5000");
    }catch(URISyntaxException e){

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //use listeners to send receive messages
        mSocket.connect();
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnection);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectTimeOut);
        mSocket.on("message", onNewMessage);
    } 
    /**
    * Callback on Socket Connection
     */
    private Emitter.Listener onConnection = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //connected                    }
                });
            }
        };

        /**
         * Callback on Socket Connection Error
         */
        private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       //connection error
                    }
                });
            }
        };

/**
 * Callback on Socket Connection TimeOut
 */
 private Emitter.Listener onConnectTimeOut = new Emitter.Listener() {
       @Override
       public void call(final Object... args) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //try to reconnect here
            }
        };


  /**
   * Callback on New Message Received
   */
  private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
       @Override
       public void call(final Object... args) {
           mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                        //handle the message here
                 }
              });
           }
        };

    public void send (String msg) {
      //just emit on an event and register the event on the server side
      mSocket.emit("send",msg);
      //you can customise the message
    }
```

Comment: A little explanation what you changed would improve the answer drastically.